# SQL Server 2012 Read Only Connection

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

How can I setup a read only connection to sql server 2012 without the need to create a read only user?

Comment: Please try to avoid creating new tags.

Answer (score -1):

Connection String property [ApplicationIntent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx)

From the docs:

> Declares the application workload type when connecting to a server.
>   Possible values are ReadOnly and ReadWrite. For example:

```
ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly
```

Comment: `ApplicationIntent` is used to [allow the use of read-only server replicas](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alwaysonpro/2013/08/02/connect-to-sql-server-using-application-intent-read-only/). If you have only one server, it won't have an effect, and if the server you end up connecting to is not read-only, you will be allowed to make changes even with the `ReadOnly` intent.